# PHP json_encode not encoding... why?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've the following array in a $arrayResult:

```
array (size=1)
  'Records' => 
    array (size=1498)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'code' => string '9999999' (length=12)
          'nome' => string 'XXXXXXXXX' (length=39)
          'contrato' => string '67971' (length=5)
          'status' => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'code' => string '777777777' (length=12)
          'nome' => string 'WWwwwwwww' (length=40)
          'contrato' => string '67725' (length=5)
          'status' => string 'C' (length=1)

    .... (other results with the same pattern)

    $resultArray = $view->getAllAccounts();
    $final['Records'] = $resultArray;
    echo json_encode($final, true);
```

**when I get the array and use the json_encode nothing happens.**

Comment: peculiar looking php array - how is this derived?

Comment: try $final = $resultArray;

Comment: json_encode expects the second parameter to be an integer, why do you provide a boolean?

Comment: I think you are confusing the second parameter of `json_encode()` with the second parameter of `json_decode()` Remove the second parameter from this line `echo json_encode($final, true);` to be `echo json_encode($final);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of the data-structures and code you wrote so far, if you encounter unexpected behaviour using `json_decode` and `json_encode`, use `json_last_error` and/or `json_last_error_msg` to see what happened.

Comment: perfect, didnt know about this: the error msg is Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: after encoding the contrato field to utf8(utf8_encode) it works flawless! my code to json_encode is fine, the utf8 string was the problem tks.

Comment: :-) nice, glad it was that easy.